# ImageView onClick effect in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-imageview

Please correct me where i am wrong . I am trying to show some click effect on imageview click but it is throwing nullpointer exception . where i am wrong in this code ? It is throwing null pointer exception at createAllImage()

Fragment Code

```
public class DuaFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnTouchListener {

    ImageView fear;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup  container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.dua_fragment,container,false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        createAllImage();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                fear.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0x77000000, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                fear.invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                fear.getDrawable().clearColorFilter();
                fear.invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    void createAllImage() {
        fear=(ImageView)getView().findViewById(R.id.fear);
        fear.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }
}
```

My layout file

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fear"
    style="@style/icon"
    android:background="@drawable/fear_96" />
```

Comment: Probably, fear.getDrawable() is returning null or fear is null.. Share the stacktrace (logcat) to get more help

Comment: fear.getDrawable() was throwing null pointer so i changed it to setColorFilter(0x77000000,   
PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP); . Now it does not show any exception but there is no click effect

Comment: Your ImageView has any image?

Comment: yes it is 9patch image

Comment: Ok. Share your ImageView layout... You must set the 9Patch image in android:src (and not in android:background). Please, check that

Comment: See i have updated my question . yes i have used background attribute . Because 9 patch image was not working with src

Comment: Try to retrieve the drawable via getBackgroundDrawable, then

Comment: I updated my answer... Kindly request to check... Maybe, 9patch can work with android:src after adding android:scaleType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, `fear.getDrawable()` is returning null.

So, we have two solutions.. Need to test:

**Solution 1**

`fear.getDrawable()` is null because you set the picture as `android:background`.

*I created this fixed based in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5242897/4860513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32773282/4860513)*

So, change your `ImageView` as follows:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fear"
    style="@style/icon"
    android:src="@drawable/fear_96"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"       />
```

**Solution 2**

If you want to keep `android:background` in ImageView Layout file, try to get the drawable as follows:

```
fear.getBackgroundDrawable();
```

Comment: Invalidate force the View to re-draw itself. This happen because the View does not know that you changed the drawable. That's why you must "force"

Comment: solution one is also working fine . Thanks alot @Guilherme . Can u do little  a favour i didnt understood color code 0x77000000 . and what is code for orange

Comment: 0x77000000 is a color in AARRGGBB (Alpha, Red, Green, Blue).. You can search in google for "Color in AARRGGBB format". Orange would be 0xFFFF4500 (note that 0x means that number is in hexadecimal format)

Comment: Thanks a lot it is really helpfull for me

Comment: Glad I could help you :)